# How to get all contact from gmail in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gmail-api

I tried javascript google api for this but its not working for me.When login using this code it take me logged out just after the login.I am new in the angularjs so please anyone give me solution to get all gmail,yahoo friend list to send invitation to them using angularjs.

```
function startApp() {
gapi.load('auth2', function() {
gapi.client.load('plus','v1').then(function() {
 gapi.signin2.render('signin-button', {
 scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
 fetch_basic_profile: false });
 gapi.auth2.init({fetch_basic_profile: false,
 scope:'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'}).then(
  function (){
          console.log('init');
          auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
          auth2.isSignedIn.listen(updateSignIn);
          auth2.then(updateSignIn);
        });
});
});
}
```